# matplotlib trying use arrays to define multiple plt.text statements

Tags: python, matplotlib, settext

I's trying to plot multiple text lines on a plot using arrays.  I define xpos[i], ypos[i], text[i], and xval[i], use the following loop to plot the text, then change my slider:

```
npts = 3
i = 0
mytext = np.zeros(npts,str)
xval = [1, 2, 3]
xval = [Bx, By, Beta]
yinit = 5
ydel = -0.5
xpos = [1, 1, 1]
ypos = [yinit, yinit+ydel, yinit+2*ydel]
text = ['a = %.2f','b = %.2f','c = %.2f']

# The following loop plots the text and works fine
while i < npts:
    mytext[i] = plt.text(xpos[i], ypos[i], text[i] % xval[i])
    i += 1

svalue.on_changed(update)
```

My update def has the following line which should update the text based on changes to xval[i]:

```
def update(Beta):
    By = x3*np.tan(Beta * torad)
    Bx = x3
    line.set_xdata((x1, Bx))
    line.set_ydata((y1, By))
    npts = 3
    i = 0
    xval = [Bx, By, Beta]
    while i < npts:
        mytext[i].set_text(text[i] % xval[i])
        i += 1
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.str_' object has no attribute 'set_text'
```

I hope this is clear.  I'm unable find any references on folks trying use arrays to define multiple plt.text statements.

Thanks.

Comment: That's mostly because you didn't define the variables consistently. `text`, `text1`, `mytext`,  `thermotext`... clearly you confuse yourself with which object is what.

Comment: I modified by question above as it appears in my attempt to provide a succinct question with snippets of generic code I erred.  thanks.

Comment: Ah, you initialize `mytext` as an array of strings, but later expect it to hold other, non-string objects. You could just use a list instead.

Answer (score 0):

setting

```
mytext = [None]*10
```

based on suggestion by ImportanceOfBeingErnest solved the problem.  Thanks.